# "No caching mode page found" with new SSD drive

Tags: ssd

This is mentioned during startup. I think it also says: "Assuming drive cache: write through". It's a new Intel SSD on which I've freshly installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 64bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that there's no caching mechanism for your drive, it's disabled or maybe not recognized for some reason - so the system will write directly to the drive.